# Removing single quotes from double-quoted variable element in array and run a command

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I have a script where I dinamically change the arguments which must be passed to a command (*mkvpropedit* in this case). Consider the example script below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

LANG_NAME="eng lish"

MYSETTINGS=()
MYSETTINGS+=("--edit 1")
MYSETTINGS+=("--set \"language=${LANG_NAME}\"")

echo "Count = ${#MYSETTINGS[@]}" # should be 2
set -x # enable to see the invoked command
mkvpropedit ${MYSETTINGS[@]}
```

When I run this, I get in the console:

```bash
[~] # ./test.sh
Count = 2
+ mkvpropedit --edit 1 --set '"language=eng' 'lish"'
```

But **I would like** not having the single quotes on the final invocation of *mkvpropedit*, like so:

```bash
+ mkvpropedit --edit 1 --set "language=eng lish"
```

I tried also echoing the array into a variable, and echo removes the single quote, but then I'm not able to use the variable as an argument of *mkvpropedit* because the single quotes appear again...

Of course the script has to work also if the variable is a single word, such as `LANG_NAME="eng"` . My Bash version is 3.2 (Busybox, actually).

## Updated question

Probably the example below better explains what I'm trying to do. I've changed some names to be replicable.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

TITLE_NAME="my title"

MYSETTINGS=()
MYSETTINGS+=("--edit track:2")
MYSETTINGS+=("--set \"name=${TITLE_NAME}\"")

set -x
mkvpropedit file.mkv ${MYSETTINGS[@]}
```

If I run this script, I get (due to the wrong quote):

```bash
# ./test.sh
+ mkvpropedit file.mkv --edit track:2 --set '"name=my' 'title"'
Error: More than one file name has been given ('file.mkv' and 'title"').
```

While if I run, manually:

```bash
# mkvpropedit file.mkv --edit track:2 --set "name=my title"
The file is being analyzed.
The changes are written to the file.
Done.
```

So it's definitely a quoting issue; I would like to invoke *mkvpropedit* using the array in the script.

### Using *eval*

What seems to work, at the moment, is inserting `mkvpropedit` and `file.mkv` into the array and eventually call `eval "${MYSETTINGS[@]}"`, but is it worth and safe? Isn't `eval` **evil** (pun intended)?

```bash
TITLE_NAME="my title"

MYSETTINGS=(mkvpropedit file.mkv)
MYSETTINGS+=("--edit track:2")
MYSETTINGS+=("--set \"name=${TITLE_NAME}\"")

set -x
eval "${MYSETTINGS[@]}"
```

Returns:

```bash
# ./test.sh
+ eval mkvpropedit file.mkv '--edit track:2' '--set "name=my title"'
++ mkvpropedit file.mkv --edit track:2 --set 'name=my title'
The file is being analyzed.
The changes are written to the file.
Done.
```

Comment: no-break space `echo -n my title | xxd` (`e280 af`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are no single quotes** - that's just the shell's unambiguous representation of the variable's contents when you use `set -x`. You can see that if you instead look at the array elements using `declare -p` or by printing them one at a time:

```
LANG_NAME="eng lish"

MYSETTINGS=()
MYSETTINGS+=("--edit 1")
MYSETTINGS+=("--set \"language=${LANG_NAME}\"")
```

then

```
$ declare -p MYSETTINGS
declare -a MYSETTINGS=([0]="--edit 1" [1]="--set \"language=eng lish\"")
```

or

```
$ printf '>>>%s<<<\n' "${MYSETTINGS[@]}"
>>>--edit 1<<<
>>>--set "language=eng lish"<<<
```

**However**, you almost certainly want to pass `--edit`, `1`, `--set`, and `language=eng lish` as separate tokens to the command, which means

1. quoting each token that contains whitespace or glob characters during array construction, like `language="${LANG_NAME}"` or `"language=${LANG_NAME}"`
2. double quoting the array expansion when you use it (to prevent word-splitting and filename generation - aka "split+glob")

So

```
LANG_NAME="eng lish"

MYSETTINGS=()
MYSETTINGS+=(--edit 1)
MYSETTINGS+=(--set language="${LANG_NAME}")
```

then

```
mkvpropedit file.mkv "${MYSETTINGS[@]}"
```

Note that you do not need additional double quotes around the variable expansion, because double-quoted `"${name[@]}"` expands each element of `name` to a separate  word without further tokenization - further quotes like `\"name=${TITLE_NAME}\"` would be passed to the command literally.

See also [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: Mm, that's not clear. If I add the double quotes to the final statement, i.e. ```mkvpropedit "${MYSETTINGS[@]}"``` what I get with ```set -x``` is ```+ mkvpropedit '--edit 1' '--set "language=eng lish"'```. I know it's just a representation, but the thing is I need to pass the ```--set "language=eng lish"``` text as an argument to _mkvpropedit_ and there the single quotes are added, because _mkvpropedit_ complains.

Comment: @virtualdj are you sure it's not complaining about the fact that you passed `--set language=eng lish` as a single element?` Have you tried `MYSETTINGS+=(--set language="\"${LANG_NAME}\"")`

Comment: I've added another example below, to better clarify. And I need `language` to be quoted as well, i.e. `--set "language=eng lish"` or `--set "name=my title"` (with the new example).

Comment: The link is more useful, but doesn't explain how to deal with the double quotes inside a single element, i.e. `--set "name=my title"`. So your answer doens't work, at the moment.

Comment: It's unlikely that they want the literal double quotes around `$LANG_NAME`.

Comment: @Kusalananda actually it was the title name (see the question updated script), but mine was just an example... Basically anything that has a space.

Comment: @virtualdj Well, `MYSETTINGS+=( --set language="$LANG_NAME" )` would do the right thing no matter what's in `$LANG_NAME`. The shell will keep `language=whatever string` together as one word.  You then have to remember to _use_ the array correctly: `"${MYSETTINGS[@]}"` (with the quotes!)  If you want to _add_ literal quotes, then you could obviously do that as shown, or you could just set `LANG_NAME='"English (US)"'` or whatever.

Comment: @Kusalananda Mmm, you're right... if I use `MYSETTINGS+=(--set "name=${TITLE_NAME}")` (without the outer quotes) **and** `mkvpropedit file.mkv "${MYSETTINGS[@]}"` (with the quotes) it works, with the following output `+ mkvpropedit file.mkv --edit track:2 --set 'name=my title'`. Please post it as an answer and I'll mark like so! I've tried all the combinations, minus this one :-(

Comment: @virtualdj Since steeldriver's answer here is mostly correct, we opted for modifying that instead of posting a new nearly identical answer. You should accept it if you believe it solve your issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda I could accept it, but the answer must first be rewritten again for more clarity. The `printf` stuff should be moved away (separated) and the script rewritten to have `mkvpropedit "${MYSETTINGS[@]}"` (with the quotes) together with `MYSETTINGS+=(--set "name=${TITLE_NAME}")` (withouth the outer quotes and the escaped inner quotes). Now this information is present in the answer, but not in the correct order/together.

Comment: @steeldriver I'll leave that for you to decide on. I'm not writing an answer to this as I personally think yours is adequate and shows the general gist of things.

Comment: @virtualdj, your problem aren't the single quotes Bash includes in the output of `set -x`. Your problem are the double quotes you add to the array elements. If you would run the command from the command line as `mkvpropedit file.mkv --edit track:2 --set "name=my title"`, then you add those args to array as `array=(--edit track:2 --set "name=my title")`.

Comment: The quotes there are part of shell syntax, and they work to include the space as a literal part of the string (argument to the command or array element, doesn't matter). Without them, that would be split to two strings. With `\"`, you'd add a literal quote to the argument string, which the program probably doesn't want. They seldom do. Almost in no case you need to pass literal quotes to any program.

Comment: @virtualdj, there's an example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949/170373) about using an arg with whitespace in it. If it's still unclear, please comment so we can get better examples there.

Answer (score -2):

[**Wrong**]Escape dollar sign:

```
MYSETTINGS+=("--set name=\${TITLE_NAME}")
```

Or:

```
MYSETTINGS+=('--set name=${TITLE_NAME}')
mkvpropedit file.mkv ${MYSETTINGS[@]}
```

For the variable to be expanded when executing the command

```
./test.sh
+ mkvpropedit file.mkv --edit track:2 --set 'name=${TITLE_NAME}'
The file is being analyzed.
The changes are written to the file.
Done.
```

Comment: This would fail, or at least not do what you might expect, if `$TITLE_NAME` contains spaces, tabs or newlines, or globbing patterns. Try with `TITLE_NAME='* * *'`

Comment: I'm wrong, written as `${TITLE_NAME}` instead `my title`.